# Form doesn't post to database, but page reloads without showing errors. Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, eloquent

this was working fine, but I noticed a problem yesterday, where the second image uploaded refuses to be updated. So, I decided to migrate fresh to see what the problem was. After doing this, I couldn't submit new forms yesterday. When I try to submit a new entry, the page reloads, but does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem is in validation. Try to put this

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    {{ $error }}<br/>
@endforeach
```

in your blade file.

Comment: Thanks man. Was going to delete the question because I figured the cover photo size was the issue. Thanks